# Common design interface for child classes of base class c++

Tags: c++, class, user-interface, interface

I have virtual class Car. 
From this class there are different Child classes.

In my interface, I have function

```
   ride(std::string type = "mercedes")
```

Function takes parameter type and based on this, it decides, which  car is instantiated and perform ride. 
Currently, I do something like following:

```
ride(std::string type = "mercedes")
{
  if(type =="btw")
{
  auto car = std::make_shared<BMW>();
  car.ride();

}
else if(type =="audi")
{
  auto car = std::make_shared<Audi>();
  car.ride();
}
 default
{
  auto car = std::make_shared<Mercedes >();
  car.ride();
}
}
```

What would be way to instantiate Car before if-else-loop and then just assign proper type?

Many thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't be the responsibility of the `ride` function to create derived instances. This is what a factory is for. Turning a string into a specific Car instance is a single responsibility.

Comment: It seems silly to derive from `Car` for each manufacture out there.  I would just have a `Car` class and let it store its make and model as a `std::string` data member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a factory method to instantiate the derived class based on the model and then use the base pointer to call the derived methods (`ride()`).

```
Car{
public:
  static Car* Factory(std::string type = "mercedes") {
  if( type == "mercedes")
    return std::make_shared<Mercedes>();
  else if( type == "bmw" ) 
    return std::make_shared<BMW>();
  }
  virtual int ride();
}
```

Usage:

```
Car *car = Car::Factory("mercedes");
car->ride();
```

Comment: The OP is using C++11; `override` is a safe bet.

Comment: What if my class is templates class, would be that still valid option?

Comment: @chris: Agreed. Removed the override.

Comment: @user298182 A class using templates makes no difference.